# How to live migrate Raid 6 to Raid 10 - and add hard drives in the process - using MegaCli

Tags: hardware-raid

I have a new server, that has 6 SATA HDs with 1TB each.

I am using a Hardware Raid

01:00.0 RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic LSI MegaSAS 9260 (rev 03)

The server came preconfigured with RAID 6 only using 3 Harddrives.

Now I would like to migrate from the current to a Raid 10 using all 6 Harddrives. I have installed MegaCli. The OS is Debian Squeeze.

I understood, that live migration is supported. As the server is new, and does not carry any data, I am not concerned about backup. I just want to migrate to Raid Level 10 before starting to work with the server.

I understood, that I might need to use a syntax similar to

```
MegaCli –LDRecon -CfgSpanAdd -r10 -Array0[62:0,62:1] -Array1[62:2,62:3] -Array3[62:2,62:3] -a1
```

This should define a raid 10 with 3 units a 2 drives.

Will this liv- migrate everything without trouble?

My current raid config:

```
Adapter 0 -- Virtual Drive Information:
Virtual Drive: 0 (Target Id: 0)
Name                :
RAID Level          : Primary-6, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-3
Size                : 1.816 TB
Sector Size         : 512
Parity Size         : 3.633 TB
State               : Optimal
Strip Size          : 256 KB
Number Of Drives per span:3
Span Depth          : 2
Default Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAdaptive, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Current Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAdaptive, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Default Access Policy: Read/Write
Current Access Policy: Read/Write
Disk Cache Policy   : Disk's Default
Encryption Type     : None
Is VD Cached: No
```

SOLUTION: I learned, that a migration from 6 to 10 is simple not supported - so I am going to go through the webbios and setting up the raid from the beginning.

Comment: Array RAID level migrations and resizing typically takes hours, if not days to complete. Why don't you just scrap the VD configuration and create it anew?

Comment: BTW, this rather looks like a RAID-60 with 2x3 disks than a RAID-6 with 3 disks.

Comment: You are right - I will redo the raid with the webbios. I had some problems accessing the RMM console - so was looking for a shortcut ;-). But I learned it first is not a shortcut and second would not be possible anyway, as such a migration is not supported by RLM. Anyway thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The migration types allowed are limited. As per the the documentation for *MegaRAID SAS Software*, section *3.7.4 Migrating the RAID Level of a Virtual Drive*:

> Migrations are allowed for the following RAID levels:
>
> - RAID 0 to RAID 1
> - RAID 0 to RAID 5
> - RAID 1 to RAID 5
> - RAID 1 to RAID 6
> - RAID 5 to RAID 6

So migrating from RAID level 60 to 10 simply would not work.