# Convert RAID 5 to RAID 10 without data loss

Tags: dell-poweredge, hardware-raid, raid5, windows-sbs-2011, raid10

I have a Windows SBS 2011 server on a Dell R610 with RAID 5 configuration [3 disk].

Is there a way to convert it to RAID 10[4 or 6 disk] without losing anything or needing to re-install the whole OS and all the applications?

Comment: I seriously doubt it.

Comment: Recently, I installed Dell Open Manage and in the web interface under the storage there is an option says reconfigure but don't want to risk loosing data and reloading os

Comment: It would heavily depend on the controller installed. Which one is it? The LSI gear supports reconfigration / capacity expansion, but the choices are very limited, RAID5 to RAID10 would not work with LSI controllers: http://serverfault.com/a/481870/76595

Comment: PERC 6/i Integrated Raid Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few DELL raid controllers that supports "online capacity extension" (and this is exactly what you want! (; ). Here is an article covering this topic (sorry - I only found this german ressource)

http://de.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/922.online-capacity-expansion-oce-raid-level-migration-rlm.aspx

Comment: PERC 6/i Integrated Raid Controller   --Danke

Comment: PERC 6/i Integrated Raid Controller   --Danke                            I Think this will work actually I just need to find a english version or figure out few lines that didn't get translate by chrome. I was in the same exact screen but except wasn't sure how risky to was to click on it. I will still do the back up as O'connor and Rob suggested and update you guys.

Comment: Thank You Schmiel and Thank you everyone specially O'Connor and RobM I will try this and update you guys in next week :) ty

Comment: Good Luck! :) - Worked for me several times but depending on your array size it may take a looong time to complete.

Comment: One More question.. When I start this process does server stays online??  or goes offline and a rough idea on your past experience about the time line [i have raid 5[3x disc] 1TB each [total size is 1.81TB 1.30TB free]

Comment: the server stays online the whole time. i was extending a 4 disc 2 TB RAID6 to 4 TB - that took about 40 hours

Comment: wow ty for the the update

Answer (score 3):

The only sane, sensible course of action is to back up and verify all your data before trying anything like this, just in case.

And if you're going to do that then you might as well go ahead and delete the old RAID array afterwards, and create a new one that is configured the way you want it to be. It's boring but if you do anything properly it's just about the only way that's guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming.. the new RAID layout presents itself to the OS in the same way as the previous RAID 5 device did..

**Here be dragons**

You could:

1. Take an image with Clonezilla.
2. Nuke the RAID layout, and add your disk, making it RAID 10.
3. Use Clonezilla to squirt the image of your server back onto the disk.

It might be possible with other backup/imaging/clone tools too.